# How to convert epoch time to GMT + 7 time in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column created_date which is in epoch format. I wanted to use a filter condition as shown below.

Dataframe sample

```
    created_time   updated_time       sys_time  last_action_time account_id  \
0   1624473000000  1624459148023  1624459148023                 0        812   
1   1624471920000  1624448094358  1624448094358                 0        812   
2   1624469400000  1624455267579  1624455267579                 0        812   
3   1624466580000  1624466620020  1624466590321                 0        812   
4   1624466529000  1624466610222  1624466540086                 0        812   
5   1624466501000  1624466610270  1624466510212                 0        812   
6   1624466461000  1624466620149  1624466469825                 0        812   
7   1624466443000  1624466446558  1624466446558                 0        812   
8   1624466435000  1624466460213  1624466460213                 0        812 

daily_data_df = [(data_df['created_time'] >= start_date_int) & (data_df['created_time'] < end_date_int)
```

Where,
start_date_int & end_date_int is GMT+7 timezone 
created_time is epoch format

Please help me with the conversion.

Comment: You need help on the filtering or not ?  If yes, please provide also sample data of start_date_int & end_date_int

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the epoch time to `GMT+7` using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`dt.tz_convert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_convert.html), as follows:

```
data_df['created_GMT+7'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['created_time'], unit='ms', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Etc/GMT+7')
```

**Result:**

```
print(data_df['created_GMT+7'])

0   2021-06-23 11:30:00-07:00
1   2021-06-23 11:12:00-07:00
2   2021-06-23 10:30:00-07:00
3   2021-06-23 09:43:00-07:00
4   2021-06-23 09:42:09-07:00
5   2021-06-23 09:41:41-07:00
6   2021-06-23 09:41:01-07:00
7   2021-06-23 09:40:43-07:00
8   2021-06-23 09:40:35-07:00
Name: created_GMT+7, dtype: datetime64[ns, Etc/GMT+7]
```

Then, filter the rows as follows:

```
start_date_int = 1624466460500
end_date_int = 1624469402000

mask = data_df['created_GMT+7'].between(pd.Timestamp(start_date_int, unit='ms', tz='Etc/GMT+7'), pd.Timestamp(end_date_int, unit='ms', tz='Etc/GMT+7'))
daily_data_df = data_df.loc[mask]
```

Or,

```
start_date_int = 1624466460500
end_date_int = 1624469402000

mask = ((data_df['created_GMT+7'] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01", tz='Etc/GMT+7')) // pd.Timedelta('1ms')).between(start_date_int, end_date_int)
daily_data_df = data_df.loc[mask]
```

**Result:**
(using the sample `start_date_int` and `end_date_int` above)

```
print(daily_data_df)

    created_time   updated_time       sys_time  last_action_time  account_id             created_GMT+7
2  1624469400000  1624455267579  1624455267579                 0         812 2021-06-23 10:30:00-07:00
3  1624466580000  1624466620020  1624466590321                 0         812 2021-06-23 09:43:00-07:00
4  1624466529000  1624466610222  1624466540086                 0         812 2021-06-23 09:42:09-07:00
5  1624466501000  1624466610270  1624466510212                 0         812 2021-06-23 09:41:41-07:00
6  1624466461000  1624466620149  1624466469825                 0         812 2021-06-23 09:41:01-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

First : Strip last 3 digits from column "created_time", it seems that epoch lengh is only 9-10 and you have 13 :

```
df['created_time'] = df['created_time'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:-3])
```

Second : Convert from Unix epoch to datetime :

```
df['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'], unit = 's')
```

Third : Filter date range (below sample date range) :

```
start_date_int = '2021-06-23 18:12:00'
end_date_int   = '2021-06-23 18:30:00'

df_filterd = df[(df['created_time'] >= start_date_int) &\
                (df['created_time'] <  end_date_int)]
```

*Alternative method for filter :

```
df_filterd = df[df['created_time'].between(start_date_int , end_date_int)]
```